# Magento : issue in shopping cart

Tags: magento

first I'm developping an extension for custom price so when i add a product to cart with 400$ and add again the same product with 500$ it gives me in total 1000$ like described in image bellow :

[image]

so this is not logic an d the total must be 900$ now i wanna solve that problem but i don't know where to start I've been confused i wanna do like this :

[image]

Comment: you mean, to add +price when change custom options? And to display that product which have different custom option, in next row?

Comment: yes that's what i want :p @DRAJI

Comment: which version you are using? Its default option. when you select any custom option in that same sku of that product, automatically, it will come into the next row with custom option

Comment: latest version 1.8.1.0

Comment: yeah. are you using any custom theme?

Comment: http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/custom-product-option-and-its-use-case-in-magento/  please check this tutorial. It may help you. I think, you have been missing something in your module.

Comment: do u understand the question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May i know the products are different. if the products having same sku it will take only one price.

For this u need to add two products with same name and different "SKU". I think it will work..

Comment: the same sku but i wanna do like the second img :(

Comment: is there any possibility fot this ?